# Need good RDLC (Reports) examples/samples

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I am in evaluation phase of report tool.

I prefer RDLC for the same. But I need some examples/samples available in the wild which can guide us on using the RDLC off the shelf.

I would be looking for examples from as simple as list of data and as complex as using matrix, calculation, grouping, etc.

This will help us to make a reference point if anytime we get stuck up somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to look at [FastReport .NET](http://www.fast-report.com/en/products/FastReport.Net.html). It can open RDLC reports too.