# Are there any good samples for using Sqlite in WinRT / XAML?

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, winrt-xaml

So many people expect there to be a database in Windows 8 XAML development. But there is nothing native. There is, however, Sqlite for WinRT. There aren't, however, any excellent examples. Does anyone know of any excellent examples of using Sqlite in WinRT?

Here's the Sqlite download site: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

I see Tim Heuer's article (http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) but it is from June and deals with pre-Release Windows 8.

I see Erik Jensen's article (http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/08/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-windows.html) it is excellent, but not really step-by-step.

Would be great to see more use of this technology.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: Seems like StackOverflow is designed to help answer common developer questions that keep them from getting their development done. Asking for other developer's resources on a hard-to-find topic is a commonly recurring type of question on Stack. You should look.

Comment: That's not quite right.  If your question was "how to do I connect to sqlite from winrt" then that's right on target, but asking for links, as I assume you are given the examples you gave, is off-topic.

Comment: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/ For the release preview

Comment: These "sample" ques are not closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833050/good-workflow-foundation-samples
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200606/good-app-documentation-samples
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540130/good-domain-driven-design-samples
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676183/vs2010-dsl-samples

Comment: These "sample" ques are not closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749674/jquery-samples
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088491/good-samples-of-using-finalizers-in-c-sharp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684407/where-could-i-find-some-uml-samples

Comment: These "sample" ques are not closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897050/need-good-rdlc-reports-examples-samples
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245717/drawing-signal-with-a-lot-of-samples
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337680/good-samples-of-software-development-use-cases

Comment: Closing this question is inconsistent, at least

Comment: By the way, the question "how do I connect to SQLite from WinRT" is nonsensical. If those are the questions you are waiting for, then I expect more and more questions to be incomprehensibly closed.

Comment: How is it possible that WinRT, XAML and Windows 8 development be 'off topic' in a Windows 8 tag? This is the essence of the topic in the first place. What is happening to SO?!

Comment: This question wasn't closed because it was looking for how to do things.  It was closed because it asked for a link to an outside source and there really isn't a good way to answer it without doing so.

Comment: That reasoning doesn't make sense in the context of StackOverflow. There are hundreds of questions asking for links. And, I might add, most are not closed. So, closing this question JUST because it is like other questions StackOverflow is remarkably inconsistent and impolite. Not to mention that this is a good question that is asked frequently.

Comment: I always vote to close questions that are only asking for links if there is no way to change the question such that it doesn't require links.

Comment: Great, here come the power tripping, trigger happy closers. I came here from google, looking for this exact answer. I see this far too often these days and it's getting quite annoying.

Comment: @Kohan that's how I feel, too. //mydogisbox// is the worst. I feel like he has caused damage to the quality of stack overflow in his "moderating". His "handiwork" is throughout SO. Aweful.

Comment: I was was quite frustrated at the time, went on a rant post, suggesting a "fix" at meta. I later realised someone had suggested the same thing already; so I closed my question and commented on theirs. The idea was rejected by the powers that be, but it's worth a read. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22503/feature-request-new-system-for-agreeing-and-discussing-on-whether-to-close-ques/22540#comment448793_22540

Comment: [SQLLite example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-SQLite-in-a-Windows-c16aea77) of the SQLLite